# Position Absolute/Relative Nightmare

Tags: html, css

I'm almost crying. Okay, not that much. But I spent almost three days trying to find a solution for this problem and I can't find anywhere.

I'm using Bootstrap, so only a part of the CSS is available as the main classes I use the default from Bootstrap.

This is what I want to achieve:
[image: Menu Header Image]

This is what it's looking like right now (both mobile and desktop)

[image: Menu Header Image Desktop Medium Resolution]

[image: Menu Header Image Desktop Big Resolution]

The live website: http://acessogestaocontabil.com.br/

And this is the code:

**HTML**

```
<!-- navHeader -->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="header">

        <div class="container d-xl-none">
            <a href=""><img src="img/footerLogo.png" class="img-fluid" alt=""></a>
        </div>

        <div class="midias d-none d-xl-block">

            <nav>
                <a href="http://"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a> | <a href="http://"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            </nav>

        </div>

        <div class="container d-none d-xl-block">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-9">
                    <nav class="nav">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="index.php" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="sobre.php" class="nav-link">Sobre</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Consultoria e Assessoria</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a href="servicos1.php" class="dropdown-item">Assessoria Contábil</a>
                                <a href="servicos2.php" class="dropdown-item">Pessoas</a>
                                <a href="servicos3.php" class="dropdown-item">Fiscal</a>
                                <a href="servicos4.php" class="dropdown-item">Tributária</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="blog.php" class="nav-link">Blog</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="contato.php" class="nav-link">Contato</a></li>
                    </nav>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

**CSS/SASS**

```
#header {
    background-image: url('../img/bg-topo-desk.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 195px;
}

#header .nav {
    background: url('../img/bgHeaderMenu.jpg') no-repeat #13165f;
    position: absolute;
    transform: none;
    width: 100%;
    top: 133px;
    right: -184px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

#menuHeader {
    position: relative;
    right: 210px;
}

#header .nav a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#header .nav .nav-item {
    border-right: 1px solid  #3249b7;
}

#header .midias {
    background: url('../img/bgSocialHeader.jpg') no-repeat #3d5cc7;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 133px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 6px 180px 5px 60px;
}

#header .midias a {
    color: #FFF;
}

// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    #header .midias {
        display: none;
    }
}

// Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px)
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
    #header .nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

The logo is inserted into the image, so it will show as a normal background in desktop. In mobile, I change to the a inserted image, with a link. I know is not the best scenario but it's what I was capable to do.

The navigation menu is the main problem. It looks okay in some resolution, but when I try to resize, it just breaks. I tried everything: two divs, two backgrounds, flexbox, position absolute, position relative and everything just fails.

Does anyone knows how to solve it? :(

Comment: Please include a minimum viable example so that we can see how it works. Also, for what I can say - you most likely don't want to use absolute positioning at all and instead you should replace it with some actual layout method.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of issues you're facing. Could you elaborate more on that? Furthermore I don't see any breakpoints declared in the provided CSS, but you do talk about "mobile styling". A working example of your code would be really helpful.

Comment: You have an image of the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @MichałSadowski I Michal, I added the images for what the website currently looks like. I help it will better clarify what is my problem :) I tried flexbox but I think it'm too newbie to put this to work with flexbox.

Comment: @LeVic Hey, yeah. The first image is what I'm trying to achive. The last two images is what currently looks like (just added)

Comment: @JasonK Hey Jason, I added the live website. What I'm trying to achieve is what I put in the first image. But my current situation is the last two images (you can check the live website to see the nightmare haha).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I can suggest is - move the background to its own element, then you can remove all `position: absolute` declarations, as the other elements will neatly fall below it. As the image should, as I understand, displayed whole, the easiest way is to just use `<img src="/img/bg-topo-desk.png" alt="header" style="width:100%"/>`. (of course you should move the width declaration to css).